# Beta distribution and Wiener process

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

Suppose $W(t)$ is the standard Wiener process on $[0; 1]$ and $\{T_x\}_{x \in \mathbb{R}}$ is a collection of random variables defined by the following relation:
$$T_x = \mu(\{t \in [0;1] | W(t) > xtW(1)\})$$

Here $\mu$ stands for Lebesgue measure.

Is it true, that $\forall x \in \mathbb{R} \exists y(x) \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $T_x \sim Beta(y(x), y(x))$?

I know, that it is true for $0$ and for $1$ ($T_0 = \mu(\{t \in [0;1] | W(t) > 0\})$ is known to be distributed as $Beta(\frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{2})$; $T_1 = \mu(\{t \in [0;1] | W(t) -tW(1) > 0\})$ is known to be distributed uniformly on $[0; 1]$ which is the same as $Beta(1, 1)$).  However, I do not know what to do with $x \in \mathbb{R}\setminus \{0; 1\}$

Comment: I think you have a typo in Beta(1/2,1/2,1/2)

Comment: It may be convenient to represent $W(t)$ as a sum of a Brownian bridge $B(t)$ and an independent Gaussian $t W(1)$. If one can find an expression for the distribution of $S_y = \mu(\{t \in [0;1] \mid B(t) > y t\})$, then one can also describe the distribution of $T_x = S_{(x-1) W(1)}$ (as the family of random variables $S_y$ is independent from $W(1)$).

Comment: Some crude simulation suggests that $Beta(\frac{x+1}{2}, \frac{x+1}{2})$ may be a fairly close distribution for $x \in (0,1)$ but not outside this interval. In any case the distribution of $T_x$ looks symmetric about $\frac12$, which makes sense to me

Comment: The same crude simulation seems to suggest that $T_x$ and $T_{2-x}$ may have the same or similar distributions